# PVC has non-bound phase ("Pending")

Tags: kubernetes

So i'm deploying two PVC and one POD which references them
When I try to create them, the PVC's get created with Pending state. The Pod exits immediately once these errors happen:

```
Error processing volume "data" for pod "storage-0-2_test(74facf84-b8ef-4d62-b001-3f1d9f000291)": 
error processing PVC "test"/"data-storage-0-2": PVC test/data-storage-0-2 has non-bound phase ("Pending") or empty pvc.Spec.VolumeName ("")
```

Relevant parts of the yaml are listed below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: logs-storage-0-2
  namespace: test
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: local-storage
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: data-storage-0-2
  namespace: test
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 15Gi
  storageClassName: local-storage
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
  name: storage-0-2
  namespace: test
spec:
...
  containers:
  - env:
...  
    volumeMounts:
...
    - mountPath: /var/opt/hdfs/datanode
      name: data
      subPath: datanode
    - mountPath: /var/log
      name: logs
      subPath: hadoop
...
  volumes:
  - name: data
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: data-storage-0-2
  - name: logs
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: logs-storage-0-2
...
```

I do have PersistentVolumes of required sizes available in this namespace

Comment: which is the status of your pv ?

Comment: i have plenty of available PVs of the desired size. the status shows "available"

Answer (score 0):

I see two things that can be done here:

1. Check if your storage class is in healthy state and make sure it is the default storage class. Also check if you can manually create a `PersistentVolume` and connect it without issues.
2. If above is not the case than there might be something that already takes your `PV` or it is not being freed properly. A workaround in that case would be to just create extra `PVs` and see if that solves the problem.

Please let me know if that helped.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:**
Kubernetes does not bound PVC until it is mounted in the deployment.

**Long Answer:**
I have also faced this issue and resolved it. After the creation of PVC the status was in pending state. After searching for sometime seems like there was no issue.

I then moved on to create a deployment and in that deployment I have used this PVC. After applying the deployment, I checked the state of PVC, its status was changed to **Bound**.

IMO maybe after creating the PVC first time, kubernetes does not bound it until it is mounted in the deployment.

P.S: I am new in kubernetes.